# Functional Google 2FA code (via SMS) received from a random (but in use) mobile phone number

Tags: authentication, passwords, multi-factor, google, sms

**tl;dr for those who are misunderstanding my post:** imagine your friend who uses GMail suddenly tells you they have 2FA enabled, and logged in to their account, and that the 2FA code (SMS) they received upon requesting it came from **your** number. That would be impossible, right? That's what happened here, except it wasn't between two friends in this case, but between me and a complete stranger.

**Original post:**

I have a Google account, and for various reasons, I decided to activate 2-factor authentication (2FA) for my account (i.e., input your password, and confirm the login by typing in a 6 digit code sent to your registered mobile phone number). I did this about a month and a half ago.

The first few codes I received came from a sender identified as "Google" by my phone/service provider. Then, on the 21st of January 2020, I received the 2FA code from a mobile number, when I tried to log in. At that time, I didn't think much about it. I just presumed that Google was probably using a couple of additional numbers and whatnot as backups when there were too many 2FA codes to be sent out or whatever. However, I did retain the SMS, as I was surprised to receive it from what was clearly a regular mobile phone number.

Since then, every single 2FA code I've received has been sent by "Google", and I've never received another code from a mobile number of any sort (or for that matter, from a sender with an identifiable number). Being a bit curious, I called that random number from which I had received the code then, and much to my surprise, somebody actually answered.

They seemed equally surprised by the fact that I had received a 2FA code from their number, and were utterly confused. They gave me their first name and location, and told me I could find them on WhatsApp (which I couldn't; I tried using another person's phone to try and find them on WhatsApp, but that didn't work either).

I am really confused now, and I thought I'd turn to the SE community for some inputs.

Some information that might be pertinent in this discussion:

- All the "regular" 2FA code messages are always in English (here's the newest one here; I always delete the messages once I use the code, which is why I don't have a history here).
  [image: google_og]
- The errant code I received was in German (I live in Germany, the sender's number is also a German number; the person I spoke with confirmed it by stating where they lived). The person told me that they use Google (Gmail?) as well. A text I sent them (after we spoke) asking if they are actually reachable on WhatsApp can also be seen in the screenshot below (I haven't received a response as of the time of writing).

[image: google_weird]

- The errant code **worked**. I had logged in successfully with it, which is what surprised me the most.
- I received a "Critical Security Alert" from Google on the **19th of November 2019**: "Google noticed unusual activity in your account. Someone else might have signed in and deleted emails. Review your account activity to make sure no one else has access." However, as far as I could tell, I did not lose any data, and I did not see any suspicious activity either, and this was long before I even activated 2FA anyway.
- I don't see anything unusual in the Google Accounts Security page.
- As far as I know, none of my accounts (with Google or elsewhere) have been compromised.
- If it helps, I use Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X230 at home (and another Ubuntu 18.04 machine at work). My phone is a ZTE Axon 7 running Android v.7.1.1 (there is no way for me to update it!). I can provide a list of apps and the likes if that will be helpful.

My question is: what is going on? Is it possible for a 2FA code to be sent like this?

Comment: FWIW, for some service I receive a 2FA code from a "named" number, but if click resend, I get it from what looks like a real number, +1... (I don't live in the US). While SMS for 2FA is questionable, I've always seen the problem as contents exposed. I guess it's possible someone has changed your phone in Google account to their number, and is intercepting those codes and resending (but why not just use then?).

Comment: I dont know about the part "somebody actually answered." but google and other companies use third party messaging for sending 2FA codes and such

Comment: @VipulNair as I mentioned in the OP, the mobile phone is registered to an ordinary citizen who was extremely surprised that I had received **my** 2FA code from **their** phone number. What you've mentioned here is **NOT** what happened in my case. The same goes for domen's comment. If somebody did accidentally register my number in their account, how did it (the registration) even get validated to begin with? As far as I can tell, what's happened here should be impossible.

Comment: like domen said it sounds like they changed your #... you might be seeing a fake google login page, that just allows them to then login... so you think you're logging in, but really you're sending your login to them... then they login and re-direct the SMS to you...  they might have already used it, but you aren't entering it on the site you think you are but a spoofed site.  Or, they send it to allow you to login from the device registered to do so, but they are still in between.  So either MITM or cross-site attack or combination...

Comment: you may want to follow some of the advice given in this thread: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224553/two-factor-authentication-turned-on-for-my-google-account-phone-but-still-ha/224580#comment459319_224580 btw, the # was probably spoofed, so the person you called is likely not involved.

Comment: @pcalkins as far as I can tell, the time it happened, I did not log in at a spoofed site. All my browser sessions on all my devices are under private browsing mode in Firefox, and my accounts do not have any "trusted" devices identified to them as such. And, if my account has been compromised, why haven't I lost access to it? As I pointed out in the OP, it's been a couple of weeks now since the incident happened (and I haven't changed the password in the meantime). Further, I checked app authorizations and the likes, and nothing has changed. I'll take a look at the link you've posted, thanks.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175607/3644. The SenderID of SMS can be spoofed.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder oh wow. That's just appalling. So is it possible this person's phone number was being used as a relay to send me the 2FA code **without** them being aware of it? Wouldn't that be illegal?

Comment: My guess is that your telecom provider has some kind of one in a million race condition that causes an SMS to get the wrong source. It's probably happened hundreds or thousands of times, and you just happened to be paying attention.

Comment: Please contact your telecom provider. They should have logs and should be able to find out what really happened.

Comment: I actually contacted Google in the meantime, and they seems to be in the process of investigating this issue. I'll contact my provider as well once I hear back from Google.

Comment: the nexus between him getting the 2fa code from an odd number and the critical security alert from google implies that it's not a glitch with his provider...

Comment: I can't give you a conclusive explanation for this phenomenon, but maybe I can put your mind a little more at ease: When I still used SMS 2FA, I (German) have once received a valid Google 2FA code to my German mobile phone number from a random Portuguese number that apparently belongs to Vodaphone PT in 2018. Every other code before and after - even on the same day - always came from "Google". As far as I am aware, my Google account has never been compromised. I have also received 2FA codes for other services from random numbers with no identifiable connection to these services.

Comment: There is nothing in your post that suggests that anything is wrong or that there is a threat or compromise of your account. The ***only*** issue here is the number reported by your carrier as the source. Regarding your edit, there is no impact to anyone's security or privacy.

Answer (score 4):

The SenderId of an SMS can be easily spoofed by anybody betweeen Google and your phone. Note that Google does not directly send you an SMS but uses service providers that have network connections (maybe indirectly) to your phone. And since the Telcos between Google and your phone want to filter out non-person-to-person traffic (because of $), it makes sense for someone on the route to make the SMS look like person-to-person (p2p) traffic by choosing a (random) SenderId that comes from a p2p number. And if that number is already in use, even better. :-)

I work at an SMS aggregator who develops 2FA, delivers SMS for 2FA, uses SMS routes, and has heard of SenderId spoofing.